# how to use non-blocking way to check stdin is empty or not

Tags: c, windows, terminal

I want to read keyboard operations, some keys will generate `ESC[...`, when I read `ESC`, I want to judge whether the ESC key is pressed or other keys. (That is, when I read it, how to check stdin are there any characters in the buffer?)

I turned off the line input mode, in linux I can use the following code to solve the problem:

```
int check_keydown()
{
#if defined _WIN32

#else
     int ch = 0;
     int res = read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1);
     if (res > 0)return ch;
     return -1;
#endif
}
```

But I don't know how to achieve the same function in windows.

(I checked the source code of ncurses, it uses `ReadConsoleInput` to read keyboard operations,that is not what I want. I want to know how to **check stdin buffer is empty or not** by **non-blocking way**)

Can someone tell me what to do, thanks in advance.

Comment: You better utilize a library such as `ncurses`

Comment: @EugeneSh. (In fact, I asked this question because I didn't plan to use it)

Comment: Since ncurses is open-sourced, you can look into the sources and see how it is done there. I'm sure you need to call some Windows specific functions.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that approach in Linux.  Terminal devices are a little quirky, but generally speaking, `read()`ing from a file that is not configured for non-blocking mode will, in fact, block until at least one byte can be transferred or an error or EOF is encountered.

Comment: @thebusybee sounds great, I searched for a while, but didn't find it.

Comment: [_kbhit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit).

Comment: @IInspectable I tried it, _kbhit only check key is pressed or not

Comment: Well, [using "source code ncurses"](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=source+code+ncurses) reveals lots of hits... What did you do?

Comment: @thebusybee I mean I didn’t find it in its source code.

Comment: @thebusybee ncurses uses ReadConsoleInput to read keyboard operations, that is not what I want.

Comment: Please add this information to your question ([edit] it), and add _why_ it is not what you want, and what you want instead. This point is not clear yet.

Answer (score 2):

Get the number of inputs available to read, Windows|Linux:

```
int get_unread_input_count()
{
  #ifdef _WIN32
    DWORD n;
    return GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents( GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &n ) ? (int)n : 0;
  #else
    int n;
    return ioctl( STDIN_FILENO, FIONREAD, &n ) ? 0 : n;
  #endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For nonblocking IO, you can use [poll](https://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) or possibly [select](https://linux.die.net/man/2/select) on `stdin`:

```
#include <stdio.h> // stdin
#include <poll.h> // int poll(struct pollfd *fds, nfds_t nfds, int timeout);

struct pollfd fd;
fd.fd = STDIN_FILENO;
fd.events = POLLIN; // "There is data to read."
fd.revents = 0;
int ret = poll(&fd, 1, 0);
if (ret > 0 && (fd.revents & POLLIN != 0))  {
  // got some data
}
else {
  perror("poll failed on stdin");
}
```

Comment: emmm, I want it work on Windows

Comment: my bad, I misunderstood. Is using mingw or cygwin an option? I believe it would let you use your current POSIX code.

Comment: Sounds great, but I have decided to use `PeekConsoleInput` and `ReadConsoleInput`.